# Bootstrap columns collapsing too early

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am a junior web dev and I am making my first website as an intern to a company.
I used bootstrap to make the structure, but when I resize Chrome, the col-xs-12 class seems to be collapsing at 892px, instead of 767px. Why does this happen? Here is my media query structure, if it helps.

It also seems that some elements react to their media query properties later than it should happen. For example, on max-width 639, if I set properties to an element, the inspector only reads them at 559. Any ideas on why is this happening? I've been trying to find a solution for hours now. :(

```css
*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[MEDIA QUERIES]----------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 1919 ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 1919px){
 body{
  background: peru;
 }
}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 1599 ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 1599px){
 body{
  background: lightcoral;
 }
}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 1359 ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 1359px){
 body{
  background: lightblue;
 }
}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 1199  ]-------------*/
/*------------------ Bootstrap MD ----------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 1199px){
 body{
  background: magenta;
 }
}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 1079 ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 1079px){
 body{
  background: lightgreen;
 }
}

/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 991  ]-------------*/
/*------------------ Bootstrap SM ----------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 991px){
 body{
  background: cyan;
 }
}

/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 767  ]-------------*/
/*------------------ Bootstrap XS ----------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 767px){
 body{
  background: violet;
 }
}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 719 ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 719px){
 body{
  background: brown;
 }

}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 639 ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 639px){
 body{
  background: pink;
 }
}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 559  ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 559px){
 body{
  background: yellow;
 }

}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 479  ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 479px){
 body{
  background: blue;
 }

}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 399 ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 399px){
 body{
  background: orange;
 }

}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 359  ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 359px){
 body{
  background: green;
 }

}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[ 0 - 319  ]-------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 only screen and (max-width : 319px){
 body{
  background: red;
 }

}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------[THE END]--------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
```

OK, a small update. My bootstrap col XS seems to have a break-point at 691px instead of 767px. I have tried linking bootstrap locally, from CDN, commenting the media queries, it still behaves the same...There is a 50-100px difference (depending on the media query) that makes everything to be hazy.

Comment: Your media queries seem to be working properly: https://jsfiddle.net/24yscugg/ The number in the fiddle shows the output window width which the media queries trigger from which is triggering the correct colour. Are there any other examples we could look at? Screenshots or JSFiddle - thanks.

Comment: Thanks! That sure helps alot!

Comment: I've had this problem - don't know why is happening, my resolve every time was to simply copy the code(html or css) in another file

Comment: slightly off topic but they better be paying you for interning. And Peru sounds like a curious colour....!!

Comment: Why have you chosen to use `max-width` instead of `min-width`? Bootstrap is "Mobile First" so it uses `@media (min-width: 123px) { .. }` to apply new rules as the screen size increases. It seems counter intuitive (to me at least), to complicate things by introducing `max-width` selectors as well.

Comment: @Martin . It's a win-win situation. I get the practice, and they get my help. It's only for 3 months, so I can live with that. It's more like a career reorientation.

Comment: @KirkBeard thx, will sure try that aswell.

Comment: @sTx trying that now...let's see. Keep you posted ;)

Comment: The media queries seem to be working fine and you mentioned that the elements react to their media query properties later than it should happen.elements react to their media query properties later than it should happen.

OK, I might know the solution to this. As crazy as it sounds, you may have zoomed in/out into your browser that changed the viewport. Happened to me before. Close your browser and reopen.

Comment: Hello. I have solved the issue. It was something with my PHP structrure, though I can't explain exactly what. I refreshed the project in a new structure and everything works fine now. THANK ALOT guys !